# How to create a list of links to post with specific category

Tags: posts, categories

I'm trying to create a list of links to post that are tagged a specific category. Is this possible?  I'm not even sure where to begin. Any help?

so, for example I'm trying to show the 1st ten post that are tagged "video".

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by putting this where you want to display the list :

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

In here all you need to do is replace the category ID with your desired categ ID. `'category' => 1 and that's all